# Why does my Listbox only works when it is binded to a function?

Tags: silverlight

It is strange, I thought listbox can only be binded to Properties, Not functions.

But "Products" is a Function, i dont understand how it can bind to a function.

also, when I try binding it to productsViewModel, it doesnt work, nothing shows in the browser :(

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,5,5,5">
....
</ListBox>
```

```
    public ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> productsViewModel = new ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>();        
    public ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> Products
    {

       get { return productsViewModel; }
    }
```

Comment: `Products` looks like a property to me

Comment: `Products` __is__ a propery not a function (note the `get`).

Comment: You cannot bind to a function as you noted; Products is a Property as stated.

Comment: productsViewModel is a field, and there is no functions in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx):

```
private int _myField = 0;
```

This is a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

```
public int MyProperty
{
     get { return _myField; }
     set { _myfield = value; }
}
```

This is a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx):

```
public int Method(object parameter)
{
     return 42;
}
```

You are binding to a property.

Bindings require you to bind to public properties. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) if you are new to binding.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just another question. Does the property has to have get and set defined in order to be accessed by other classes? I thought as long as they are defined as public, it does not matter :)

Comment: For access by other classes only the `public` modifier is important, if the getter is missing the value cannot be read, if the setter is missing it cannot be assigned to.